# nvim treesitter compilation error while loading

Tags: neovim, treesitter

This error comes while i open nvim

I copied config from my old pc and pasted to new pc,
the same config worked in other pc

nvim-treesitter[rust]: Error during compilation
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

Answer (score 0):

You need to install GNU Standard C++ Library (`libstdc++`).

You didn't mention your Linux distribution but on a Debian one, you can install the `libstdc++` with command `sudo apt install libstdc++6`

Comment: its Ubuntu 22.04 , but it is installed